# Problem with Sync from Andoid Calender

Tags: google, google-calendar

I have a google calender that is sync to my Cellphone samsung Galaxy S2.

It does not working when I apply a new appointment time in my google calender in my android. It says that it's syncing but no appointment time will be displayed in the calender, both in android and website.

However it works perfectly when I apply the appointment time in my google calender at "https://www.google.com/calendar". When I apply the new date, I'm enable to sync it and see it in my android.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the calendar sync does not work when the phone is "full", i.e., far over half of available storage is used by all your downloaded apps, and pictures, documents etc. In my case, I don't remember the exact numbers, but with some 90 % usage, but still say half a gigabyte free, this turned out to be not sufficient for Calendar. I removed some unused apps, and Calendar started syncing again.